# 2nd button shows alerts but won't run function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Craps game in javascript for an intro class I'm teaching. I have the initial "Come out" roll working and displaying a second button to roll for point. On clicking the 2nd button, it will display alerts, but it won't overwrite the paragraph ID's with the new roll information. It's holding my point variable value and writes that to an alert box, but it won't write that to the document. I'm copying and pasting my entire page. I've done testing, so things are commented out for testing purposes.

```
<!-- INCOMPLETE -->
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            var point = 0;  
            function intro()
            {
                document.getElementById('button2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('intro').innerHTML = 'This is the Come-Out roll.<p>Click the button to roll.</p>';
            }

            function pointRoll()
            {
                alert("test");
                //  while (pointDice01 + pointDice02 != point)
                //  {
                //      var pointDice01 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                //      var pointDice02 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

                        document.getElementById("Dice01").innerHTML = point;
                        document.getElementById("Dice02").innerHTML = point;
                //  }
            }


                function main()
                {

                    // Math.random returns a number between 0 and 1, but not including 1.
                    // Thus, we have to multiply by the number we want to go to (6)
                    // We use the floor to round down and we add 1 so 0 is not included.
                    var dice01 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                    var dice02 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

                    document.getElementById("dice01").innerHTML = dice01;
                    document.getElementById("dice02").innerHTML = dice02;

                    // if (Condition to lose the game) else if (Condition to win) else (keep playing)
                    if(dice01 + dice02 == 2 || dice01 + dice02 == 3 || dice01 + dice02 == 12) // Come out roll. Crapped out
                    {
                        total = dice01 + dice02;
                        document.getElementById("pointPara").innerHTML = "Total is " + total + ".";
                        document.getElementById("crapResults").innerHTML = "You Crapped Out! Roll again.";
                    }
                    else if (dice01 + dice02 == 7 || dice01 + dice02 == 11) // Come out roll. A Natural, Pass line wins
                    {
                        total = dice01 + dice02;
                        document.getElementById("pointPara").innerHTML = "Total is " + total + ".";             
                        document.getElementById("crapResults").innerHTML = "A Natural! Pass line wins!!! Roll again.";
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("buttonPara").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        document.getElementById("button2").style.visibility = "visible";
                        point = dice01 + dice02;
                        //alert(point);
                        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = "";
                        document.getElementById("pointPara").innerHTML = "Your point value is " + point + ".<p>Try to reach this number again before rolling a 7.";
                        document.getElementById("crapResults").innerHTML = "";
//                      return false;
                    }
                }   

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad = intro()>
        <p id = "intro"></p>


        <p id = "buttonPara"><button onclick = "main()">Click Me.</button></p>
        <p id = "dice01"></p>
        <p id = "dice02"></p>
        <p id = "pointPara"></p>
        <p id = "crapResults"></p>

        <p><input type="button" id = "button2" value = "Click here for point." onClick = "pointRoll();" /></p>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
document.getElementById("Dice01").innerHTML = point;
document.getElementById("Dice02").innerHTML = point;
```

You have specified the element names in captial case. Change it to

```
document.getElementById("dice01").innerHTML = point;
document.getElementById("dice02").innerHTML = point;
```

and it works

Comment: I feel like such a schmoe. I should have seen that. I have the whole thing finished now and the whole game works now, start to finish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You are providing id in wrong case.

```
document.getElementById("dice01").innerHTML = point;
document.getElementById("dice02").innerHTML = point;
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("Dice01").innerHTML = point;
document.getElementById("Dice02").innerHTML = point;
```

Looking at your code, I think you want to set:

```
document.getElementById("dice01").innerHTML = pointDice01;
document.getElementById("dice02").innerHTML = pointDice02;
```

Instead of setting value of `point`.